# In an Ubuntu terminal how can I keep a python program going?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I recently got my own VPS and intend to run my discord bot off of it. However the main problem I am encountering is when the PuTTY session is closed then the program turns off even though the server remains on.

How can I make the program a process that stays on forever until I choose to end it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on ubuntu in a terminal window when you start the python program use the nohup command (man page synopsis):

nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

For example:

```
$ nohup /tmp/a.out /tmp/data
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
$
```

Comment: Or, since OP's program appears to be a python program, `nohup python mybot.py arg1 arg2 ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the any script files in background by giving ampersand (&) symbol at the end of file name in terminal.

Example:

```
sudo filename.py &
```

This keeps on running even if you close the putty session.